# WxWidget - Problem with wxFrame itself - is it possible to copy an element from one wxFrame to another

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets, wxmathplot

The task is simple - Is it possible to copy one element from wxFrame, for example wxButton to another wxFrame that has been created later on ?

I've tried from simplest solution like "Ctrl + c", up to cutting the element from one wxFrame to another, but nothing worked.

Unfortunately there is no code to be shown

The result is simple: i want one element copied to another frame/dialog/window, therfore i can create similar wxFrame

~ The IDE is CodeBlock ~

Comment: You must be asking about some GUI editor, not doing it in the code, right? If so, you should probably mention which editor are you using.

Comment: @VZ. edited - sorry

Comment: Not directly answering your question but I find it easier to do a draft design in wxFormBuilder and then fine-tune the code in a separate editor, such as VS. In this way, you can copy paste whatever you want...